# Ruby Rails - Copy From Postgres to CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, copy, export

I need to run a ruby program in ruby on rails that exports data from the Postgres DB to CSV files.  This program will run daily and handle millions of lines of data, so I put the command in SQL.

```
query = "copy (select plays.* from plays inner join games on games.id=plays.game_id where games.league=3 and games.date >= '1995-01-01' and games.date <= '2017-07-23') to '/home/stuff9000/sports/public/processed_data/ncaaf_plays.csv' with csv header"

connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
connection.execute(query)
```

This draws the following error

```
ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from a file (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
```

So I changed the query command to

```
query = "\\copy (select plays.* from plays inner join games on games.id=plays.game_id where games.league=3 and games.date >= '1995-01-01' and games.date <= '2017-07-23') to '/home/stuff9000/sports/public/processed_data/ncaaf_plays.csv' with csv header"
```

and I get

```
syntax error at or near "\" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 1: \copy (select plays.* from plays inner join games on games.i...
        ^
```

So how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't figure out how to do this with the `copy` command. I adjusted the copy command to point to STDOUT instead of write a file.  Then had ruby process the STDOUT to file.  This turns out to be pretty fast at a glance.

```
query = "COPY (select plays.* from plays inner join games on games.id=plays.game_id where games.league=3 and games.date >= '1995-01-01' and games.date <= '2017-07-23') to STDOUT with csv header;"
destination = "/results.csv"

csv = []

connection_pool = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool
connection = connection_pool.checkout

raw_connection  = connection.raw_connection
raw_connection.copy_data(query) do
  while row = raw_connection.get_copy_data
    csv.push(row)
  end
end

connection_pool.checkin connection

sql_data_as_string = csv.join("")

File.open(destination, "w") {|file| file.write(sql_data_as_string.force_encoding("UTF-8"))
```

Comment: Just to clarify: `raw_connection.copy_data(copy_data) do ...` should be `raw_connection.copy_data(query) do ...`